# Working with JPG into Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

i have a compressed image i am trying to receive it and show it on android plat-from , in vcl i have been doing something like  following

```
procedure TForm1.CreateJpg(Data: string);
var
  JpegStream: TMemoryStream;
  JpegImage: TJPEGImage;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  tmpPos, tmpLen: integer;
  pp: string;
begin

  try
    tmpPos := Pos('B]>', Data);
    pp := Copy(Data, 5, tmpPos - 5);
    tmpLen := StrToInt(pp);
    Data := Copy(Data, tmpPos + 3, tmpLen);
    Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;

    try
      JpegImage := TJPEGImage.Create;

      try
        JpegStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

        try
          TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeStream(Data, JpegStream);
          JpegStream.Position := 0;
          JpegImage.LoadFromStream(JpegStream);
        finally
          JpegStream.Free;
        end;

        with Bitmap do
        begin
          Canvas.Lock;

          try
            Width := JpegImage.Width;
            Height := JpegImage.Height;
            Canvas.StretchDraw(rect(0, 0, 200, 160), JpegImage);
          finally
            Canvas.Unlock;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        JpegImage.Free;
      end;

      img.Assign(Bitmap);
    finally
      Bitmap.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      //
  end;
end;
```

but i cannot do the same into android because there is no declaration of `TJPEGIMAGE` library i am not sure if i can do something as alternative of `JPEG` on `Fire-monkey` i am confused about what i have to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The VCL uses `TGraphic`-derived classes to handle individual image types.  However, there is no equivalent of `TGraphic` in FireMonkey.  It has only a single [`TBitmap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap) class that supports multiple image types.  Different FMX platforms support a different subset of image types (see [Supported Image Formats](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmapCodecManager#Supported_Image_Formats) for the complete list).  Fortunately, JPG is one of only two image types that are supported on all FMX platforms (PNG is the other).

The FMX equivalent of your VCL code would look something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.CreateJpg(Data: string);
var
  JpegStream: TMemoryStream;
  Jpeg, Bitmap: TBitmap;
  tmpPos, tmpLen: integer;
  pp: string;
begin
  try
    tmpPos := Pos('B]>', Data);
    pp := Copy(Data, 5, tmpPos - 5);
    tmpLen := StrToInt(pp);
    Data := Copy(Data, tmpPos + 3, tmpLen);

    Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      Jpeg := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        JpegStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
        try
          TIdDecoderMIME.DecodeStream(Data, JpegStream);
          JpegStream.Position := 0;
          Jpeg.LoadFromStream(JpegStream);
        finally
          JpegStream.Free;
        end;

        with Bitmap do
        begin
          SetSize(Jpeg.Width, Jpeg.Height);

          if Canvas.BeginScene then
          try
            Canvas.DrawBitmap(Jpeg,
                {$IF RTLVersion >= 31} // 10.1 Berlin or higher
                Jpeg.BoundsF,
                {$ELSE}
                TRectF.Create(0, 0, Jpeg.Width, Jpeg.Height),
                {$IFEND}
                TRectF.Create(0, 0, 200, 160), 1.0);
          finally
            Canvas.EndScene;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        Jpeg.Free;
      end;

      img.Bitmap.Assign(Bitmap);
    finally
      Bitmap.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      //
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thank you remy , note `Jpeg.BoundsF` has no member called BoundsF

Comment: @Vlark.Lopin: I didn't notice you were using Seattle.  [`BoundsF`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.BoundsF) was added in Berlin.

Comment: i think its in the tokyo version only

Comment: @Vlark.Lopin: No, it was added in Berlin. The link above is from the Berlin documentation. I have updated my answer to account for that.

Comment: yes thank you but sadly the image not showing when its assigned to the `Timage`  `img.Assign(Bitmap);`

Comment: @Vlark.Lopin: unfortunately `TBitmap` lacks any kind of useful error reporting. If `LoadFromStream()` or `DrawBitmap()` fail, NO exception is raised, unlike in VCL.  So you are just going to have to debug the code to track out what is actually failing.